# Getting image dimensions returning null

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dropzone.js

I am getting a null value when trying to get an uploaded images dimensions

Here is my code

```
<div class="flex-grid" *ngFor="let f of files_dropped">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col"><ngx-dropzone-image-preview ngProjectAs="ngx-dropzone-preview" id="sky" [file]="f" [removable]="true" (removed)="onRemove(f)"></ngx-dropzone-image-preview></div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col"><ngx-dropzone-label>{{ f.name }}</ngx-dropzone-label></div>
                <div class="col"><ngx-dropzone-label>({{ f.type }})</ngx-dropzone-label></div>
                <div class="col"><ngx-dropzone-label>({{ f.size }})</ngx-dropzone-label></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

  onSelect(event) {
    this.files_dropped.push(...event.addedFiles);
    const formData = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i < this.files_dropped.length; i++) {
      formData.append("file[]", this.files_dropped[i]);
      console.log(this.files_dropped[i]);
      var myImg = document.querySelector("#sky") as HTMLImageElement;
      var realWidth = myImg.naturalWidth;
      var realHeight = myImg.naturalHeight;
      alert("Original width=" + realWidth + ", " + "Original height=" + realHeight);
    }
  }
```

This is the exact error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'naturalWidth' of null`. I am trying to get the width  and height of each uploaded image. Here is a stackblitz that has the upload functionality I am using

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-dropzone-mg6mrz

Comment: I am guessing ```myImg``` is null. Try checking if your query selector is wrong or the html markup when it is rendered after the image upload to see what you need to query.

Comment: @tomerpacific yes myImg is null, not sure where to put the id

Comment: Because you are using angular, you should not use `id` at all. Use `@ViewChild( 'sky')` with `<ngx-dropzone-image-preview #sky ..`. But that will only give you the Component of  dropzone. From there you would have to find the image. An easier way might be to use files dropped directly, i assume it contains a `File[]` and you could use that to get the image dimensions using this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL . Can you complete the stackblitz, so that it is acutally usable?. Then i could provide the code

Comment: I tried a live example of <ngx-dropzone-image-preview> via https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-dropzone?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. When you drop an image in the last area, you can see that an <img> is added to the DOM. So I think your selector shouldn't be "#sky" but instead "#sky > img".
But it will probably work only for one image because all of your <ngx-dropzone-image-preview> will have the same id.

Comment: @x4rf41 I have removed the code that was breaking the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-dropzone-mg6mrz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL` without using any id by using the files directly:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.files_dropped.length; i++) {
  formData.append("file[]", this.files_dropped[i]);
  const reader = new FileReader();
  // this triggers after readAsDataURL() is called
  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    // create a new image 
    const img = document.createElement("img") as HTMLImageElement;
    // need to wait for it to be loaded to get the natural dimension
    img.onload = () => {
      console.log(img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
    }
    // set the data url as src
    img.src = reader.result as string;
  }, false);
  // read the file as a data url (compatible with img.src)
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files_dropped[i]);
}
```

Important: You cannot get the image dimensions synchronously because the image has to be loaded first and the onSelect event is called before the image is loaded.

Full example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-dropzone-pu5tep?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Will this work also on a list of iamge elements?